# Page reloading on second click on another anchor using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I make Ajax call for deleting a single record, it works for the first time and refreshes the table content correctly but when I want to delete another record, it reloads the entire page(preventDefault() not working), I don't know why.
can anyone help me

my HTML code

```
<div class="box">
        @if ($departments->isEmpty())
            <div class="box-header">
                <h1>
                    هیچ ریاست موجود نیست
                </h1>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title">لیست ریاست ها</h3>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>شماره</th>
                            <th>ریاست به دری</th>
                            <th>ریاست به پشتو</th>
                            <th>ریاست به انگلیسی</th>
                            <th>تغیرات</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($departments as $department)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $department->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $department->nameInDari }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $department->nameInPashto }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $department->nameInEnglish }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ $department->id }}" class="edit">
                                        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{{ $department->id }}" class="delete text-danger">
                                        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
        @endif
    </div>
```

here is my Ajax code

```
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('.delete').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            id = $(this).attr('href');
            url = '{{ route('departments.destroy', ':id') }}';
            url = url.replace(':id', id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: url,
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {
                        reloadContent(data.success);
                    } else {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
function reloadContent(data) {
            $('tbody').html('');
            var row = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                row = '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + value.id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.nameInDari + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.nameInPashto + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.nameInEnglish + '</td>' +
                    '<td><a href ="' + value.id + '" class ="edit">' +
                    '<span class ="fa fa-edit"></span></a> ' +
                    '<a href ="' + value.id + '" class="delete text-danger">' +
                    '<span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('tbody').append(row);
            });
        }
</script>
```

here is my Laravel code

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $department = Departments::find($id);
    if ($department) {
        Departments::destroy($id);
        return response()->json(['success' => Departments::all()], Response::HTTP_OK);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'No Record Found with ID = ' . $id], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check whether click() function is working on click at second record?

Comment: No, it's not working @ankit.jbp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change `$('.delete').click(function(e)` to `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e)`

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr('href');
        url = '{{ route('departments.destroy', ':id') }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: url,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {
                    reloadContent(data.success);
                } else {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**justify:**

at first delete the `reloadContent(data)` fire and added a new `.delete`
elements so the method in its old form will not fire on the new elements & use the default dehaviour of `<a>`

these edits change the method from bind to live for more info please check the following article [difference between on() and live() or bind()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind-in-jquery/)